# Unable to draw SKLabelNode in front of UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, sklabelnode

I'm adding a SKLabelNode in my GameScene.swift by using the following code

```
 let scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "GillSans-BoldItalic")
    scoreLabel.fontSize = 25
    scoreLabel.text = "Text"
    scoreLabel.position = position
    scoreLabel.zPosition = 3000
    self.addChild(scoreLabel)
```

However, when the label appears it is behind a UIView (that contains a couple of UIImageView elements), despite it's intentionally high .zPosition.

How can I make it appear in front of my UIView? I can't find a .zPosition equivalent on UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zPosition` only relates to other nodes within the same scene. If you have a `UIView` that has been added on top of your `SKView` that holds the scene, subviews of this view will always appear on top of nodes in your scene. Consider adding your images as nodes inside your `SKView` instead of in their own view.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response! How would I do that? My scene is held by a UIViewController which doesn't allow for self.addChild().

Comment: If your question is how to add images to a scene, you can do that with `SKSpriteNode`. Your view controller should have a reference to your scene. Something like `self.scene.addChild()`

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, that's exactly what I'm doing and it's not working. In the description, I say it clearly that I'm adding it to the Scene in the way you described.

Comment: Hi there, he's right. If you have a scene imagine it's a box with layers and you put on layer 3000 inside this box your stuff. Now you have an UIView on top of the box... imagine what happens ...